# Inserir apóstrofos com variáveis

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou efetuando uma consulta através de um valor armazenado em uma variável. Essa variável é declarada `DECLARE @it_codigo varchar(max)` e obtém valor de um campo `ntext` de outra tabela, através de uma procedure.

```
SELECT * FROM anaProdutos WHERE cod_produto LIKE  '' + @it_codigo + ''
```

Tentei também utilizar a função `QUOTENAMES` e mesmo assim continua não inserindo os apóstrofos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para fazer o escape do <kbd>'</kbd>, use dois apóstrofos:

```
SELECT * FROM anaProdutos WHERE cod_produto LIKE '''' + @it_codigo + ''''
```